# How to add tags completion to org mode capture?

Tags: org-mode

I use org mode's capture functionality to make all my todo's. It is clean and practical and let me add a consistent content to all my todo's, including a prompt for heading, a prompt for tags and an automatic insertion of created date. Here is my code:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '((
     "t"                ; key
     "Todo"             ; description
     entry              ; type
     (file+headline "C:/.../org/notes.org" "tasks")       ; target
     "* TODO [#B] %^{Todo} :%^{Tags}: \n:PROPERTIES:\n:Created: %U\n:END:\n\n%?"  ; template
     :prepend t        ; properties
     :empty-lines 1    ; properties
     :created t        ; properties
     )))
```

However, my prompt for tags forces me to enter tags from memory. How could I add tags from the tags list set by the following code:

```
(setq org-tag-alist `(
              ("OFFICE"   . ?o)
              ("HOME"     . ?h)
              ("ERRAND"   . ?e) ))
```

When my point is in the heading of an already created task, this list pops up when I hit C-c C-c and let me chose the tags by their short cut single letters "o", "h" or "e".

So my question is: is it possible to include this pop-up list of tags inside the code for my capture?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The built in solution is to use `%^g`.  From the help for `org-capture-templates`:

> %^g         Prompt for tags, with completion on tags in target file.
>
> %^G         Prompt for tags, with completion on all tags in all agenda files.

You can also do this "by hand" by calling some function that adds the tags.  Adding tags is generally done with `org-set-tags` (this is what `C-c C-c` is doing).  So, all we have to do is call that in our template with the `%(func)` syntax:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '((
     "t"                ; key
     "Todo"             ; description
     entry              ; type
     (file+headline "C:/.../org/notes.org" "tasks")       ; target
     "* TODO [#B] %^{Todo} %(org-set-tags) \n:PROPERTIES:\n:Created: %U\n:END:\n\n%?"  ; template
     :prepend t        ; properties
     :empty-lines 1    ; properties
     :created t        ; properties
     )))
```

If you have a specific list of tags you want to select from (say `org-tag-alist`) you can use `completing-read` to select from it:

```
(completing-read "Tag: " (mapcar #'first org-tag-persistent-alist) nil t)
```

Comment: Ahh...Beautiful! What a strong tool org mode is! And thanks a lot for your thorough answer : ) The %(org-set-tags) gave me access to the `org-tag-alist` directly without using `completing-read`. However, your code prompts for tags before prompting for todo,  which is a litle unlogical. Can the order be reversed?

Comment: I don't think the order can be changed; elisp expression seem to be the first things to be evaluated.  Possibly you could add `org-set-tags` to `org-capture-before-finalize-hook`, which would ask for tags just after you finish the capture (that is, just after using `C-c C-c`)

Comment: Needed something like this. However, when I use this code I get in the heading: "** test %![Error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 1) 0)] "

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein - think the function has changed - try`org-set-tags-command`?